Understanding Navier-Stokes equation. Laplacian of a vector field?
I'm reading Vorticity and incompressible flow (Majda), but I don't understand the Navier-Stokes equation: 
As $v(x,t)$ is a vector field, what does $\Delta v$ means? $(\Delta v^1, ..., \Delta v^N)?$
How do I write the convective derivative in terms of $v$ components? Is it something like
$$
(v_t^1+v^1v_{x_1}^1+v^2v_{x_2}^1+...+v^Nv_{x_N}^1, ..., v_t^N+v^1v_{x_1}^N+v^2v_{x_2}^N+...+v^Nv_{x_N}^N )?$$
If I write it for $N=2$, are Navier-Stokes equations
$$
v_t^1+v^1v_{x_1}^1+v^2v_{x_2}^1=-p_{x_1}+\nu \Delta v^1 \\
v_t^2+v^1v_{x_1}^2+v^2v_{x_2}^2=-p_{x_2}+\nu \Delta v^2 \ ?
$$

$$\Delta v = \Delta (v_x, v_y, v_z) = (\Delta v_x, \Delta v_y, \Delta v_z)$$

As in comments $\Delta\newcommand{\del}{\partial}$ is applied component wise: $(\Delta v)^j = \Delta v^j$. The given formula for the convective derivative is also meant to be understood in this way: $(\frac{Dv}{Dt})^j = \frac{Dv^j}{Dt} = \del_t v^j + (\sum_{k=1}^N v^k \del_k) v^j$.
Yes for your formula for the convective derivative.
Yes for $N=2$. Might be clearer to write as (for simplicity $\nu=1$)
\begin{align}
\del_t v^1 + (v^1 \del_1+v^2\del_2) v^1 = - \del_1 p + \Delta v^1\\
\del_t v^2 + (v^1 \del_1+v^2\del_2) v^2 = - \del_2 p + \Delta v^2
\end{align}
and for $N=3$,
\begin{align}
\del_t v^1 + (v^1 \del_1+v^2\del_2+v^3\del_3) v^1 = - \del_1 p + \Delta v^1\\
\del_t v^2 + (v^1 \del_1+v^2\del_2+v^3\del_3) v^2 = - \del_2 p + \Delta v^2\\
\del_t v^3 + (v^1 \del_1+v^2\del_2+v^3\del_3) v^3 = - \del_3 p + \Delta v^3
\end{align}
Just to be absolutely clear -  the $i $th component of $(w\cdot \nabla) v$ in dimension $N$ is
$$((w\cdot \nabla) v)^i = (w^1 \del_1+w^2\del_2+\dots+w^N\del_N) v^i $$

small aside - $(\Delta v)^j = \Delta v^j$ is because we're using cartesian coordinates.  The coordinate free definition is $\Delta v = \nabla(\nabla \cdot v) - \nabla\times(\nabla \times v)$ (see wiki1), and see wiki2 for examples in specific coordinates.

For an incompressible  flow the momentum density is $ p = \rho \vec v$, its kinetic energy density is $E_{\text{kin}} = \frac{1}{2}\rho \vec v^2 $.
If one is following in time the path of fixed, differentially small volume $\text{dV}$,  transported over the boundary $\partial M$ of a macroscopic volume $M$, e.g. a 2-plane in a  3-volume, the component of momentum tensor transport is $ v_1 \vec p = \rho v_1  \vec v $,  and the component of the kinetic energy transport vector is $ v_1 \ (\frac{1}{2} \rho \vec v^2 )$.
This fact is the source of nonlinearity in transport equations of the density of entities involving  powers of velocity itself.
Energy density is pressure by units
$$\left[T\right] =\frac{\frac{\text{kg} m^2}{s^2}}{m^3} = \left[p\right]=\frac{\frac{\text{kg} m}{s^2}}{m^2} $$  and so the change in kinetic energy is forced by pressure gradient $\nabla P$.
By some simplifying physical conditions, the Galilei transform
$$\frac{d}{dt} \to \frac{D}{dt} + \vec v \cdot \nabla$$
generates the substancial time derivative $D$  and
Stokes identity yields a nice invariant differential expression  of the time change of $T$ in the comoving tangent frame,
$$\rho \vec v\cdot \left( \text{curl}\left( \text{curl} \vec v\right) \right) $$
that is nothing more the the well known Hodge
$$*d*d*\omega$$ of the 1-form $$\omega = *v,$$ corresponding to the velocity vector field. In flat euclidean space in cartesian coordinates it can be expanded as
$$\rho \vec v\cdot\left( \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \vec v\right) \right) = \rho \vec v \cdot \left( \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec v) - \nabla^2 \vec v \right) $$
by the rules for the multiple cross products, poor man's physical, conventionally rule dominated replacement for exterior algebra and calculus in euclidean flat $\mathbb R^3$.
Today we define in Mathematicy eg
X = Sequence[x, y, z]
V = Sequence[u, v, w]
VX = Through[V[X]]

Sequence[u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]]

Curl[Curl[{VX}, {X}], {X}]

Converted to standard  representation

Here the $\cdot$ maps the operator into the vector onto components
Obviously there is lacking the third second derivative for a Laplacian in each row; supplementing it, one produces a grad div term
$\nabla\left( \nabla \cdot \vec v \right)= $
$$
The conversion from Mathematica output form  to physical standard representation  can be accomplished e.g. by
      std = {Derivative[n__][f_][X] :> 
             Subscript["\[Del]", 
             Sequence @@ 
             Select[{x, y, z}^{n}, (# =!= 1 &)]][f]}

made possible by Mathematicas capability to process standard numerical operations like power ^ over pairs of lists
    {a, b}^{2,3} == {a^2, b^3}

